# Best way to remove a particular hardwood floor board glued to the subfloor

Tags: hardwood-floor, joints

I finished the hard wood flooring then I found that the joint board extends over the door to the bathroom. I am now working to extending the tile floor to the door, and need to replace that board.

However, the board is glued down to the subfloor. It is not tongue and grooved to the next board but I used a lot of glues (including to the side of the board). I do not want to damage the adjacent board.

What is the best solution to remove this particular board?

PS

The glue used is gorilla wood glue + construction glue.

Comment: Adding the glue type you used to the question might help, but think it will need to be cut out and might be come out in pieces.  Most glues are almost permanent bonding of two surfaces( that's what they want us to believe).

Comment: Think you will have to cut the joints/edges first.  A good back saw should do the edges without damage.  The board itself will probably be ruin, since the glue will have bonded to the board and sub floor.  Do you think the whole board needs to come up or can you cut a section out to meet/fit the tiles?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I would prefer to have the whole board come up. The board does not need to be saved. I need to make sure that the clean edge of the next board is preserved.

Comment: use a plunge oscillating saw to carve out the glued part.